# How to add dynamic table rows to Wordpress database with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, wordpress, dynamic-tables

this is my first post here, I hope I will follow all the rules. I haven't found any answer that fits exactly to my question. I'm currently developing a Wordpress plugin and have coded a dynamic table with jQuery where rows can be added, sorted and removed dynamically. Each row has input fields in it. Now I want to save each rows input field data as a new database entry in my custom database table. I have already managed to have a jQuery variable that has each rows field entries with commas separated. Now I basically just need to get this variable into the database query and thats where I'm stuck. Maybe the jQuery variable is also the wrong way to go. Can you guys help me out?

My jQuery:

```
    jQuery(".save-inv").click(function () {
      x = [];
      jQuery('table tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
        y = '';
        jQuery(this).find('td input').each(function () {
            y += jQuery(this).val() + ',';
        });
        if (y != '') {
            x.push(jQuery.trim(y))
            alert(y);
        }
      });
    });`
```

The alert(y); returns the comma seperated values of the input fields. At this point I would want to insert the call to the database insertion but don't know how yet.

My php/HTML (Wordpress Shortcode format)

```
    $showlist = '<a href="#" class="add-item-btn et-pb-icon" style="font-size: 30px; color: #0c71c3;"></a> Add row<br>';
$showlist .= '<a href="#" class="save-inv et-pb-icon et-waypoint et_pb_animation_top et-animated" style="font-size: 30px; color: #0c71c3;"></a> Save<br>';

//Form Definiton
$showlist .= '<form name="new-inv" method="POST" action="">';

// Header row
$showlist .= '<table id="inv-list" style="width:100%">';
$showlist .= '<thead><tr>';
$showlist .= '  <th></th>';
$showlist .= '  <th>Item name</th>';
$showlist .= '  <th>Description</th>';
$showlist .= '  <th>Category</th> ';
$showlist .= '  <th>Amount</th>';
$showlist .= '  <th>Exp. Date</th>';
$showlist .= '  <th>Alert Date</th>';
$showlist .= '  <th></th>';
$showlist .= '</tr></thead>';


// First item row
$showlist .= '<tbody id="fbody><tr class="item-row">';
$showlist .= '  <td style="padding: 6px 0px 0px 30px"><img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/draggable.png" style="height: 30px;"></td>';
$showlist .= '  <td><input type="text" name="itemname"></td>';
$showlist .= '  <td><input type="text" name="desc"></td>';
$showlist .= '  <td><input type="text" name="cat"></td>';
$showlist .= '  <td><input type="text" name="amount" size="5"></td>';
$showlist .= '  <td><input type="date" class="datepicker" name="expdate"></td>';
$showlist .= '  <td><input type="date" class="datepicker" name="alertdate"></td>';
$showlist .= '  <td><a href="#" style="font-size: 25px; color: #0c71c3;" class="del-item-btn et-pb-icon"></a></td>';
$showlist .= '</tr></tbody>';

$showlist .= '</table></form>';
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google wp ajax loads of tutorials out there

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need php to talk to the database.  So have your jQuery send request to a plugin or php page that will then insert into the database.  Be careful as you can introduce new security holes with this if you aren't careful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess you are talking about SQL injection attacks. I'll make sure to strip the input of any sensitive symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this to database than you have to use php,

but your inputs is from jQuery so you can use ajax to send request to php file or function and write the code there to insert into database.

```
jQuery(".save-inv").click(function () {
  x = [];
  jQuery('table tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
    y = '';
    jQuery(this).find('td input').each(function () {
        y += jQuery(this).val() + ',';
    });
    if (y != '') {
        x.push(jQuery.trim(y))
        alert(y);

        jQuery.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
              data: 'y='+ y + '&action=add_newraw',
              success: function(data) 
              {   

                // On sucess whatever you want to do 
                // I think nedd to just redirect to the listing page 

              }
          }); 
    }
  });
});
```

And For php code write the following function to your plugins main file,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_newraw', 'prefix_ajax_add_newraw' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_newraw', 'prefix_ajax_add_newraw' );

function prefix_ajax_add_newraw() {
$rowsId = trim($_POST['y']);

 // Write your insertion code here 

}
```

Hope This will help, you can ask freely if want any other guidance.